# ubuntu software center not opening

Tags: software-center

I  just installed ubuntu 12.04 by completely  removing windows. Now i am unable to open ubuntu software center . however i am able to see the icon on my desktop. 
suppose i can open the software center successfully...  how can i install the required drivers ? can i use the cds(drivers , webcam , facerecognition) that were given at the time of purchase of my inspiron ? please guide me in this respect . i wish to explore the world of linux .

Comment: Split your question in to two question :)

Comment: Hello viveksura. Your question about drivers is answered here: http://askubuntu.com/q/47506/24694 .... As for the Software center:

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2):

Drivers don't get installed from the windows cds because the windows software is made only for windows. In GNU/Linux, a lot of the drivers that you'll ever need are already running with the default kernel from installation.

As for the webcam, it probably just works. I would suggest that you install the cheese webcam utility to test it out. To install cheese, either open the software center and search for/ install it from there.. Or, hit ctrl+alt+t to get the command line. Then, run this command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install cheese -y
```

After the installation is complete, you can click the Ubuntu icon, then start typing cheese, then launch the "Cheese Webcam Booth".